# Writing to a particular directory not happening in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: php, file-io, ubuntu-12.04

I am able to write the data to a `/tmp` directory in Ubuntu but for other directories like writing to `/var` directory or `Desktop`, I am unable to write the contents. Is it a permission issue or something else since I am able to edit, modify and read any file from these directory but while writing through PHP code only in `/tmp` directory I am able to write.

My code is as follows:

```
 $output = "/tmp/image5.png";
 //$output = "/home/anand/Desktop/image5.png"

 file_put_contents($output, curl_exec($request));
```

The second `$output` is not working.

Comment: What's the return value of the function? See the manual: that will return `false` if it was unsuccessful. Writing to `/var/` is likely to require root permissions - if this is on the console, do `sudo php yourscript.php`.

Comment: Temporarily i have changed the permissions using sudo chmod ugo+rwx * but it is still not writing the files into the directory whether its /home or /var

Comment: Try a simple string first - maybe it is failing on the `curl` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the permission issue. Imagine what would happen if everyone could write in everyone's folders. Or delete from them.

You cannot write to your desktop from your PHP script because php script does not have write permission, since it is running from apache user (www-data probably).

You can write to `/tmp` directory because those files are stored only temporary and everyone can write to that folder.

If you want to write to particular folder (`/home/anand/Desktop/` for example), you need to either chown it to www-data (not recommended for your desktop folder), or use `chmod 777 /home/anand/Desktop` to give write permission to everyone (also not recommended since then other users will be able to write to your Desktop).